# How to fetch mongoDB data based on Sub Documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

below is my schema and  I want to fetch data for the year 2018. and I am trying with below code which is not working how to correct it

```
var data=await mongoose.model('revenues').find({name:'ff',"data.Year":2017});
```

revenues schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const revenueSchema = new Schema({
    AccountName: String,
    data: [{Name:String,Year:Number,Value:Number,Volume:Number}],
  });

  mongoose.model('revenues', revenueSchema);


[
{
name:'ff',
data:[
  { Name: 'G1a Revenue', Year: 2017, Value: 456908, Volume: 33490 },
  { Name: 'G1a0a Revenue', Year: 2018, Value: 789123, Volume: 32656 },
  { Name: 'G11e0 Revenue', Year: 2019, Value: 543213, Volume: 31656 },
  { Name: 'Gy1a Revenue', Year: 2017, Value: 456908, Volume: 33490 },
  { Name: 'Gy1a0a Revenue', Year: 2018, Value: 789123, Volume: 32656 },
  { Name: 'Gy11e0 Revenue', Year: 2019, Value: 543213, Volume: 31656 }
 ]
 }
]
```

Comment: what expected output??can you describe

Comment: is this accountname or name
 mongoose.model('revenues').find({"name":'ff',"data.Year":2017});

Comment: expected output 
{
name:'ff',
data:[
  { Name: 'G1a0a Revenue', Year: 2018, Value: 789123, Volume: 32656 },
  { Name: 'Gy1a0a Revenue', Year: 2018, Value: 789123, Volume: 32656 },

 ]
 }

Comment: @Vipul it's name

Comment: then the query must work as expected. if its not working, can you please share db.revenus.findOne(); so that we can see your data model

Comment: @Vipul here the output 
{
__v:0
_id:ObjectID {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Buffer(12)}
AccountName:"PIMCO"
data:Array(9) [Object, Object, Object, …]
length:9
0:Object {_id: ObjectID, Name: "G10 Revenue", Year: 2017, …}
1:Object {_id: ObjectID, Name: "G10 Revenue", Year: 2018, …}
_id:ObjectID {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Buffer(12)}
Name:"G10 Revenue"
Value:250369
Volume:32456
Year:2018
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
2:Object {_id: ObjectID, Name: "G10 Revenue", Year: 2019, …}
}

Comment: @Vipul I updated the model in the question

Comment: in your schema the key where ff is stored is by AccountName but you are querying with name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this actually works. `"data.Year":2017` means that you would like to find documents that have at least 1 field `Year` in object / array of objects `data` with value `2017`. I guess you want to filter `data` elements. Then on you need to use projection like this:

```
mongoose.model('revenues').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "ff"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "el",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$el.Year",
              2018
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Output:

```
 [
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "Name": "G1a0a Revenue",
        "Value": 789123,
        "Volume": 32656,
        "Year": 2018
      },
      {
        "Name": "Gy1a0a Revenue",
        "Value": 789123,
        "Volume": 32656,
        "Year": 2018
      }
    ],
    "name": "ff"
  }
]
```

You can check the results here: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rqel8r5GYuK)

Source: [MongoDB $filter operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Comment: @ravi Please have a look at my updated answer. I will also add link to Mongo Playground so that you can check the results.